# How to solve special characters?

Tags: html

I have this instruction to add an image:

```
 <p>
 <img src="images/kk.jpg" style=float:right";margin:1em width="311" 
  height="176" alt="studying girl"/>
 </p>
```

When I implement the code I get this error:

```
 special characters must be escaped :[>]
 special characters must be escaped :[<]
```

How can i solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the double quotes in the style attribute and your editor should recognise the img element:

```
<p>
 <img src="images/kk.jpg" style="float:right; margin:1em" width="311" 
  height="176" alt="studying girl"/>
 </p>
```

Answer (score -1):

I edited your code so you can use it directly as follow:

```
<p> <img src="images/kk.jpg" style="float:right";margin:1em" width="311" height="176" alt="studying girl"/> </p>
```